# Improving my search method

Tags: java, bluej

I have created a program that allows the user to input either a Dvd collection or a book collection.

I am fairly happy with what I have managed to achieve (still fairly new to programming) but I have an annoyance with my search method.

The search does work and returns what the user looks for but it then also prints out that nothing could be found afterwards. The reason being, I think, that the way I have written my code, means that each search parameter is read before ending and returning back to the menu.

I **think** that I maybe need to use a boolean or similar to end the loop when the conditions of the search are met.

I am sure that any experienced programmers will be shaking their head at my code...

The search method:

```
/**
 * Asks user to input Dvd title then compares 
 * with Dvd titles in collection
 * @param none
 * @return none
 */
public void searchDvd()
{
    String temp = ""; // Temporary variable to hold dvd title

    System.out.println ("\nPlease enter Dvd Title (full title) to search for: ");
    temp= Genio.getString();

    if(temp.equals(dvd1.getTitle()))
    {
        clrscr();
        System.out.println("\nDvd is present in collection at location 1 (Dvd 1 in collection):\n\nTitle: "  + dvd1.getTitle() + " \n  Director: "
            + dvd1.getDirector() + " \n  Lead Act: " + dvd1.getLead() + " \n  Run Time: " + dvd1.getRunTime() + " \n  Price: "
            + dvd1.getDvdPrice());
        pressKey();
    }
    if(temp.equals(dvd2.getTitle()))
    {
        clrscr();
        System.out.println("\nDvd is present in collection at location 2 (Dvd 2 in collection):\n\nTitle: " + dvd2.getTitle() + " \n  Director: "
            + dvd2.getDirector() + " \n  Lead Act: " + dvd2.getLead() + " \n  Run Time: " + dvd2.getRunTime() + " \n  Price: "
            + dvd2.getDvdPrice());
        pressKey();
    }
    if(temp.equals(dvd3.getTitle()))
    {
        clrscr();
        System.out.println("\nDvd is present in collection at location 3 (Dvd 3 in collection):\n\nTitle: " + dvd3.getTitle() + " \n  Director: "
            + dvd3.getDirector() + " \n  Lead Act: " + dvd3.getLead() + " \n  Run Time: " + dvd3.getRunTime() + " \n  Price: "
            + dvd3.getDvdPrice());
        pressKey();
    }

    else 
    {
        clrscr();
        System.out.println("\nSorry, there were no Dvd's found with that title to display.\n ");
        pressKey();
    }
}
```

The collection class (with main()):

```
public class Collection
{
//Declare private variables for use with class instances
private Dvd dvd1;
private Dvd dvd2;
private Dvd dvd3;
private Book book1;
private Book book2;
private Book book3;


public Collection()
{
    //array = new int[2];
    //dvd1 = dvd1;
    //dvd2 = dvd2;
    //dvd3 = dvd3;
    dvd1 = new Dvd();
    dvd2 = new Dvd();
    dvd3 = new Dvd();
    book1 = new Book();
    book2 = new Book();
    book3 = new Book();
}


public static void main(String args[])
{    
    //creates an instance of the collection class 
    Collection collection = new Collection();
    collection.menu();
}


public void menu()
{
    //declare the option field
    int option;
    char answer;     
    //start do while loop for the menu
    do
    {
        //display the menu
        clrscr();
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("\n\n~#~#~#~#~ DVD COLLECTION MENU ~#~#~#~#~\n\n");
        System.out.println("\n<><><><> DVD's <><><><>\n");
        System.out.println("1: Add (up to 3) Dvd's to Collection");
        System.out.println("2: Display Dvd Collection");
        System.out.println("3: Search Dvd Collection by collection");
        System.out.println("\n<><><><> BOOK's <><><><>\n");
        System.out.println("4: Add (up to 3) Books's to Collection");
        System.out.println("5: Display Book Collection");
        System.out.println("6: Search Book Collection by Title");
        System.out.println("7: Quit program");

        //prompt user to enter a selection
        System.out.println("\nPlease select an option (1 - 7): ");
        //use genio to get the user input
        option=Genio.getInteger();

        // Option 1 allows user to add up to 3 Dvd's to dvd collection
        if (option == 1) 
        { 
            clrscr();
            System.out.println("Enter Dvd 1 details:\n");
            dvd1.setDvdInputs();
            pressKey();
            System.out.println("Enter Dvd 2 details:\n");
            dvd2.setDvdInputs();
            pressKey();
            System.out.println("Enter Dvd 3 details:\n");
            dvd3.setDvdInputs();
            pressKey();
        }
        // Option 2 allows user to display Dvd collection
        if (option == 2)
        {
            clrscr();
            displayDvds();
        }
        // Option 3 allows the user to search the Dvd collection by title
        if (option == 3)
        {
            clrscr();
            searchDvd();
        }
        // Option 4 allows user add books to the book collection
        if (option == 4)
        {
            clrscr();
            System.out.println("Enter Book 1 details:\n");
            book1.setBookInputs();
            pressKey();
            System.out.println("Enter Book 2 details:\n");
            book2.setBookInputs();
            pressKey();
            System.out.println("Enter Book 3 details:\n");
            book3.setBookInputs();
            pressKey();
        }
        //i Option 5 allows the user to display the collection of books
        if (option == 5)
        {
            clrscr();
            displayBooks();
        }
        // Option 6 allows the user to search the Book collection by title
        if (option == 6)
        {
            clrscr();
            searchBook();
        }

    }
    // Option 7 will print a message that tells that the program may be exited
    while (option != 7);
    clrscr();
    System.out.println("You may now close the program. (click cross at top right)");
}


public void displayDvds()
{
    float totalPrice = 0;
    totalPrice = dvd1.getDvdPrice() + dvd2.getDvdPrice() + dvd3.getDvdPrice();
    int totalRunTime = 0;
    totalRunTime = dvd1.getRunTime() + dvd2.getRunTime() + dvd3.getRunTime();

    if (dvd1.getTitle() == "" && dvd1.getDirector() == "" && dvd1.getLead() == "" && dvd1.getRunTime() == 0 && dvd1.getDvdPrice() == 0 && dvd2.getTitle() == "" && 
    dvd2.getDirector() == "" && dvd2.getLead() == "" && dvd2.getRunTime() == 0 && dvd2.getDvdPrice() == 0 && dvd3.getTitle() == "" && dvd3.getDirector() == ""
    && dvd3.getLead() == "" && dvd3.getRunTime() == 0 && dvd3.getDvdPrice() == 0)
    {
        clrscr();
        System.out.println("Sorry, there were no Dvd's in the collection to display.");
        pressKey();
    }
    else  
    {
        clrscr();
        System.out.println(" \nDvd Collection:\n DVD1:\nTitle: " + dvd1.getTitle() + " \nDirector: "
            + dvd1.getDirector() + " \nLead Act: " + dvd1.getLead() + " \nRun Time: " + dvd1.getRunTime() + " \nPrice: £"
            + dvd1.getDvdPrice());

        System.out.println(" \nDvd Collection:\n DVD2:\nTitle: " + dvd2.getTitle() + " \nDirector: "
            + dvd2.getDirector() + " \nLead Act: " + dvd2.getLead() + " \nRun Time: " + dvd2.getRunTime() + " \nPrice: £"
            + dvd2.getDvdPrice());

        System.out.println(" \nDvd Collection:\n DVD3:\nTitle: " + dvd3.getTitle() + " \nDirector: "
            + dvd3.getDirector() + " \nLead Act: " + dvd3.getLead() + " \nRun Time: " + dvd3.getRunTime() + " \nPrice: £"
            + dvd3.getDvdPrice());

        System.out.println(" \nTotal cost of combined Dvd's: £" + totalPrice);

        System.out.println(" \nTotal Run Time of combined Dvd's: " + totalRunTime + " minutes.");
        pressKey();
    }
}


public void searchDvd()
{
    String temp = ""; // Temporary variable to hold dvd title

    System.out.println ("\nPlease enter Dvd Title (full title) to search for: ");
    temp= Genio.getString();

    if(temp.equals(dvd1.getTitle()))
    {
        clrscr();
        System.out.println("\nDvd is present in collection at location 1 (Dvd 1 in collection):\n\nTitle: "  + dvd1.getTitle() + " \n  Director: "
            + dvd1.getDirector() + " \n  Lead Act: " + dvd1.getLead() + " \n  Run Time: " + dvd1.getRunTime() + " \n  Price: "
            + dvd1.getDvdPrice());
        pressKey();
    }
    if(temp.equals(dvd2.getTitle()))
    {
        clrscr();
        System.out.println("\nDvd is present in collection at location 2 (Dvd 2 in collection):\n\nTitle: " + dvd2.getTitle() + " \n  Director: "
            + dvd2.getDirector() + " \n  Lead Act: " + dvd2.getLead() + " \n  Run Time: " + dvd2.getRunTime() + " \n  Price: "
            + dvd2.getDvdPrice());
        pressKey();
    }
    if(temp.equals(dvd3.getTitle()))
    {
        clrscr();
        System.out.println("\nDvd is present in collection at location 3 (Dvd 3 in collection):\n\nTitle: " + dvd3.getTitle() + " \n  Director: "
            + dvd3.getDirector() + " \n  Lead Act: " + dvd3.getLead() + " \n  Run Time: " + dvd3.getRunTime() + " \n  Price: "
            + dvd3.getDvdPrice());
        pressKey();
    }

    else 
    {
        clrscr();
        System.out.println("\nSorry, there were no Dvd's found with that title to display.\n ");
        pressKey();
    }
}    


public void displayBooks()
{
    float totalbPrice = 0;
    totalbPrice = book1.getBookPrice() + book2.getBookPrice() + book3.getBookPrice();
    int totalPages;
    totalPages = book1.getPages() + book2.getPages() + book3.getPages();

    if (book1.getBookTitle() == "" && book1.getAuthor() == "" && book1.getGenre() == "" && book1.getPages() == 0 && book1.getBookPrice() == 0 && book2.getBookTitle() == "" || 
    book2.getAuthor() == "" && book2.getGenre() == "" && book2.getPages() == 0 && book2.getBookPrice() == 0 && book3.getBookTitle() == "" && book3.getAuthor() == ""
    && book3.getGenre() == "" && book3.getPages() == 0 && book3.getBookPrice() == 0)
    {
        clrscr();
        System.out.println("Sorry, there were no Book's in the collection to display.");
        pressKey();
    }
    else  
    {
        clrscr();
        System.out.println(" \nBook Collection:\n BOOK 1: \nTitle: " + book1.getBookTitle() + " \nAuthor: "
            + book1.getAuthor() + " \nGenre: " + book1.getGenre() + " \nPages: " + book1.getPages() + " \nPrice: £"
            + book1.getBookPrice());

        System.out.println(" \nBook Collection:\n BOOK 2: \nTitle: " + book2.getBookTitle() + "  \nAuthor: "
            + book2.getAuthor() + " \nGenre: " + book2.getGenre() + " \nPages: " + book2.getPages() + " \nPrice: £"
            + book2.getBookPrice());

        System.out.println(" \nBook Collection:\n BOOK 3: \nTitle: " + book3.getBookTitle() + " \nAuthor: "
            + book3.getAuthor() + " \nGenre: " + book3.getGenre() + " \nPages: " + book3.getPages() + " \nPrice: £"
            + book3.getBookPrice());

        System.out.println(" \nTotal cost of combined Book's: £" + totalbPrice);

        System.out.println(" \nTotal number of combined book pages: " + totalPages + " pages.");
        pressKey();
    }
}


public void searchBook()
{
    String tempb; // Temporary variable to hold book title

    System.out.println ("\nPlease enter Book Title (full title) to search for: ");
    tempb= Genio.getString();

    if(tempb.equals(book1.getBookTitle()))
    {
        clrscr();
        System.out.println("\nBook is present in collection at location 1 (Book 1 in collection):\n\nTitle: "  + book1.getBookTitle() + " \nAuthor: "
            + book1.getAuthor() + " \nLead Act: " + book1.getGenre() + " \nRun Time: " + book1.getPages() + " \nPrice: "
            + book1.getBookPrice());
        pressKey();
    }
    if(tempb.equals(book2.getBookTitle()))
    {
        clrscr();
        System.out.println("\nBook is present in collection at location 2 (Book 2 in collection):\n\nTitle: "  + book2.getBookTitle() + " \nAuthor: "
            + book2.getAuthor() + " \nLead Act: " + book2.getGenre() + " \nRun Time: " + book2.getPages() + " \nPrice: £"
            + book2.getBookPrice());
        pressKey();
    }
    if(tempb.equals(book3.getBookTitle()))
    {
        clrscr();
        System.out.println("\nBook is present in collection at location 3 (Book 3 in collection):\n\nTitle: "  + book3.getBookTitle() + " \nAuthor: "
            + book3.getAuthor() + " \nLead Act: " + book3.getGenre() + " \nRun Time: " + book3.getPages() + " \nPrice: £"
            + book3.getBookPrice());
        pressKey();
    }
    else
    {
        clrscr();
        System.out.println("\nSorry, there were no Book's found with that title to display.\n ");
        pressKey();
    }
}   


public static void clrscr()
{           
    for ( int i=1;i<=50;i++)
        System.out.println();
}


public static void pressKey()
{
    String s;
    System.out.print("\nPress return to continue : \n");
    s = Genio.getString();
}
}
```

The Dvd class class is identical to this):

```
public class Dvd
{
// instance Dvd variables 
private String dvdTitle = ""; // Title of dvd set to empty
private String dvdDirector = ""; // Director of dvd set to empty
private String dvdLead = ""; // Lead actor/actress of dvd set to empty
private int dvdRunTime = 0; //Dvd run time in minutes
private float dvdPrice = 0; //Value of dvd


public Dvd( )
{
  dvdTitle = ""; 
  dvdDirector = ""; 
  dvdLead = ""; 
  dvdRunTime = 0; 
  dvdPrice = 0;
}


/
public void setDvdInputs()
{
    System.out.println("Please enter the Dvd Title: ");
 dvdTitle=Genio.getString(); 

 System.out.println("Please enter the Dvd Director: ");    
 dvdDirector=Genio.getString();

 System.out.println("Please enter the Dvd Lead Actor/Actress: ");      
 dvdLead=Genio.getString();

 System.out.println("Please enter the Dvd Run Time: ");    
 dvdRunTime=Genio.getInteger(); 

 System.out.println("Please enter the Dvd Cost: ");      
 dvdPrice=Genio.getFloat(); 
}


   public String getTitle(){
     return dvdTitle;
   }

   public String getDirector(){
     return dvdDirector;
   }

   public String getLead(){
     return dvdLead;
   }

   public int getRunTime()
   {
     return dvdRunTime;
   }

   public float getDvdPrice()
   {
     return dvdPrice;
   }      
}
```

The Book class:

```
public class Book
{
// instance Dvd variables 
private String bookTitle = ""; // Title of dvd set to empty
private String bookAuthor = ""; // Director of dvd set to empty
private String bookGenre = ""; // Lead actor/actress of dvd set to empty
private int bookPages = 0; //Dvd run time in minutes
private float bookPrice = 0; //Value of dvd


public Book( )
{
  bookTitle = ""; 
  bookAuthor = ""; 
  bookGenre = ""; 
  bookPages = 0; 
  bookPrice = 0;
}


public void setBookInputs()
{
    System.out.println("Please enter the Book Title: ");
 bookTitle=Genio.getString();

 System.out.println("Please enter the Book Author: ");    
 bookAuthor=Genio.getString();

 System.out.println("Please enter the Book Genre: ");      
 bookGenre=Genio.getString();

 System.out.println("Please enter the Book Page Number: ");    
 bookPages=Genio.getInteger(); //should be dvdRunTime = Genio.getDouble();

 System.out.println("Please enter the Book Cost: ");      
 bookPrice=Genio.getFloat(); //should be dvdPrice = Genio.getFloat();
}

   public String getBookTitle(){
     return bookTitle;
   }

   public String getAuthor(){
     return bookAuthor;
   }

   public String getGenre(){
     return bookGenre;
   }

   public int getPages()
   {
     return bookPages;
   }

   public float getBookPrice()
   {
     return bookPrice;
   }      
}
```

The Genio (user input) class:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Genio
{


public Genio()
{
}



private static String getStr() 
{
    String inputLine = "";
    BufferedReader reader = 
        new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    try 
    {
        inputLine = reader.readLine();
    }

    catch(Exception exc) 
    {
        System.out.println ("There was an error during reading: "
                            + exc.getMessage());
    }
    return inputLine;
}


public static int getInteger()
{
    int temp=0;
    boolean OK = false;

    BufferedReader keyboard = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    do 
    {
        try
        {
            temp = Integer.parseInt(keyboard.readLine());
            OK = true;
        }

        catch (Exception eRef)
        {
            if (eRef instanceof NumberFormatException) 
            {
                System.out.print("Integer value needed: ");
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Please report this error: "+eRef.toString());
            }
        }

    } while(OK == false);
    return(temp);
 }


public static float getFloat()
{
    float temp=0;
    boolean OK = false;

    BufferedReader keyboard = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    do 
    {
        try
        {
            temp = Float.parseFloat(keyboard.readLine());
            OK = true;
        }


        catch (Exception eRef)
        {
            if (eRef instanceof NumberFormatException) 
            {
                System.out.print("Number needed: ");
            } 
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Please report this error: "+eRef.toString());
            }
        }

    } while(OK == false);

    return(temp);
 }

public static double getDouble()
{
    double temp=0;
    boolean OK = false;
    BufferedReader keyboard = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    do 
    {
        try
        {
            temp = Double.parseDouble(keyboard.readLine());
            OK = true;
        }

        catch (Exception eRef)
        {
            if (eRef instanceof NumberFormatException) 
            {
                System.out.print("Number needed: ");
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Please report this error: "+eRef.toString());
            }
        }

    } while(OK == false);

    return(temp);
 }



 public static char getCharacter()
 {
     String tempStr="";
     char temp=' ';
     boolean OK = false;
     do 
     {
         try
         {
             tempStr = getStr();
             temp = tempStr.charAt(0);
             OK = true;
         }

         catch (Exception eRef)
         {
             if (eRef instanceof StringIndexOutOfBoundsException)
             {
                 // means nothing was entered so prompt ...
                 System.out.print("Enter a character: ");
             }            
             else 
             {
                 System.out.println("Please report this error: "+eRef.toString());
             }
         }

     } while(OK == false);

     return(temp);
 }



 public static String getString()
 {
    String temp="";
    try
    {
        temp = getStr();
    }
    catch (Exception eRef)
    {
        System.out.println("Please report this error: "+eRef.toString());
    }
    return(temp);
 }     
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is caused by having separate `if statements`.

```
if(something) {
}
if(somethingElse) // This is separate from the one above.
```

You can use `else if` to chain them..

```
if(something) {
}
else if(somethingelse) {
}
else {
     System.out.println("Sorry, none could be found");
}
```

or if you want your code to be more efficient and you're using JDK7+, you can use a `switch`..

```
switch(input) {
    case "Something":
         // Do something
         break;
    default:
        System.out.println("Sorry, none could be found");
        break;
}
```

and finally, if you want to keep the exact same `if` structure, then you can use a `boolean` value.

```
if(something)
{
    found = true;
}

if(!found)
{
    System.out.println("Sorry, none could be found");
}
```

I've added this last one in for the sake of completeness, but I wouldn't recommend it. Use one of the first two options.

Answer (score 1):

You only want to say no DVD's found if none of the titles are found.  You should use else if instead.  Right now you are just checking if the 3rd title isn't found then display none found even if one of the other titles are found.  These should all be elseif:

```
public void searchDvd()
{
    String temp = ""; // Temporary variable to hold dvd title

    System.out.println ("\nPlease enter Dvd Title (full title) to search for: ");
    temp= Genio.getString();

    if(temp.equals(dvd1.getTitle()))
    {
        clrscr();
        System.out.println("\nDvd is present in collection at location 1 (Dvd 1 in collection):\n\nTitle: "  + dvd1.getTitle() + " \n  Director: "
            + dvd1.getDirector() + " \n  Lead Act: " + dvd1.getLead() + " \n  Run Time: " + dvd1.getRunTime() + " \n  Price: "
            + dvd1.getDvdPrice());
        pressKey();
    }
    else if(temp.equals(dvd2.getTitle()))
    {
        clrscr();
        System.out.println("\nDvd is present in collection at location 2 (Dvd 2 in collection):\n\nTitle: " + dvd2.getTitle() + " \n  Director: "
            + dvd2.getDirector() + " \n  Lead Act: " + dvd2.getLead() + " \n  Run Time: " + dvd2.getRunTime() + " \n  Price: "
            + dvd2.getDvdPrice());
        pressKey();
    }
    else if(temp.equals(dvd3.getTitle()))
    {
        clrscr();
        System.out.println("\nDvd is present in collection at location 3 (Dvd 3 in collection):\n\nTitle: " + dvd3.getTitle() + " \n  Director: "
            + dvd3.getDirector() + " \n  Lead Act: " + dvd3.getLead() + " \n  Run Time: " + dvd3.getRunTime() + " \n  Price: "
            + dvd3.getDvdPrice());
        pressKey();
    }

    else 
    {
        clrscr();
        System.out.println("\nSorry, there were no Dvd's found with that title to display.\n ");
        pressKey();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Put you DVDs in a 'Collection', or a `List` (for example `ArrayList`) and use a for loop.

```
for (DVD dvd : dvds)
{
    if (dvd.getTitle().equals(temp))
    {
       // display logic
       break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your search code your using 2 If statements followed by an If-else

You probably meant to use a complet if-elseif-else or a case statement
ie

```
if(temp.equals(dvd1.getTitle())){
//do something}
elseif(temp.equals(dvd2.getTitle())){
//do somthing else}
elseif(temp.equals(dvd3.getTitle())){
//do something as well}
else{
//do the default behaviour
```

In your code if the first if matches you will get the dvd returned but (and assuming dvd 3 doesnt match ) the final else

```
 else 
    {
        clrscr();
        System.out.println("\nSorry, there were no Dvd's found with that title to display.\n ");
        pressKey();
    }
```

this will always be true unless the search matches dvd3

Comment: I found you at Joomla Stack Exchange but I couldn't find a way to make contact with you.  Our JUG Brisbane Meetup is tonight if you are free.  Give us a look.  (and have a look at the JSE Meta post that I wrote today.)